# Install npm package from git/github - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dom-helpers/class'

Tags: git, reactjs, github, npm, package.json

I am trying to install `React.js` package via git/github.

Package installation directly via npm works. Unfortunately [react-bootstrap/dom-helpers](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers) has a [bug](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers/pull/20) and repository owner/creator is reluctant to merge fix.

So I created my own [repo](https://github.com/GovPredict/dom-helpers) and applied manually fix. Then I wanted to install it via git/github (quicker than creating npm package and distributing it - I don't know how to do this).

So I added line to my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    [...]
    "dom-helpers": "git://github.com/GovPredict/dom-helpers.git",
```

Then I found that this repo has pretty poor `package.json` (it doesn't ues `files` option etc) and when you install it via `git` and then check path

```
./node_modules/dom-helpers/
```

you find directory without source code (only files included by default: `LICENSE`, `README.md` are present).

I made some changes and right it almost works...

I say almost, because it looks like `webpack` doesn't load repo OR... `package.json` still has errors.

When I run webpack development then I have

```
ERROR in ../~/react-big-calendar/lib/Agenda.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dom-helpers/class' in '/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib'
resolve 'dom-helpers/class' in '/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/GovPredict/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/maciejkowalski/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front
        using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/package.json (relative path: ./front)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/package.json (relative path: ./front)
          using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/package.json (relative path: ./front/dom-helpers/class)
            as directory
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class doesn't exist
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class.jsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class.json doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/package.json (relative path: ./class)
            as directory
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class doesn't exist
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class.jsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class.json doesn't exist
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib/node_modules]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/react-big-calendar/node_modules]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/node_modules]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/GovPredict/node_modules]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/node_modules]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class.js]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class.jsx]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/front/dom-helpers/class.json]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class.js]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class.jsx]
[/Users/maciejkowalski/projects/SomeProject/node_modules/dom-helpers/class.json]
 @ ../~/react-big-calendar/lib/Agenda.js 9:13-41
 @ ../~/react-big-calendar/lib/Views.js
 @ ../~/react-big-calendar/lib/Calendar.js
 @ ../~/react-big-calendar/lib/index.js
 @ ./components/under-the-dome-calendar/under-the-dome-calendar.jsx
 @ ./application.js
```

As you see something wrong is with loading files (`webpack`) or with [package](https://github.com/GovPredict/dom-helpers).

How to fix it (quality matters)?

---

**EDIT 1**

It looks like when you install files via npm package (without git) then

```
./node_modules/dom-helpers/
```

looks like

```
% ls -lah
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  14 maciejkowalski  staff   476B  6 kwi 20:45 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 maciejkowalski  staff   272B  6 kwi 21:39 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 maciejkowalski  staff   4,6K  4 lut 15:08 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 maciejkowalski  staff   593B  4 lut 15:14 activeElement.js
drwxr-xr-x   6 maciejkowalski  staff   204B  6 kwi 20:45 class
drwxr-xr-x   7 maciejkowalski  staff   238B  6 kwi 20:45 events
-rw-r--r--   1 maciejkowalski  staff   1,9K  4 lut 15:14 index.js
-rw-r--r--   1 maciejkowalski  staff   231B  4 lut 15:14 ownerDocument.js
-rw-r--r--   1 maciejkowalski  staff   490B  4 lut 15:14 ownerWindow.js
-rw-r--r--   1 maciejkowalski  staff   2,5K  6 kwi 20:45 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  16 maciejkowalski  staff   544B  6 kwi 20:45 query
drwxr-xr-x   5 maciejkowalski  staff   170B  6 kwi 20:45 style
drwxr-xr-x   7 maciejkowalski  staff   238B  6 kwi 20:45 transition
drwxr-xr-x  10 maciejkowalski  staff   340B  6 kwi 20:45 util
```

However when I install my [dom-helpers fork](https://github.com/GovPredict/dom-helpers) via git, then I have:

```
% ls -lah
total 48
drwxr-xr-x    6 maciejkowalski  staff   204B  6 kwi 21:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  610 maciejkowalski  staff    20K  6 kwi 21:43 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 maciejkowalski  staff   1,1K  6 kwi 21:43 License.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 maciejkowalski  staff   4,6K  6 kwi 21:43 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 maciejkowalski  staff   9,3K  6 kwi 21:43 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   12 maciejkowalski  staff   408B  6 kwi 21:43 src
```

So something wrong is with build process.

How to fix it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo