# Installing npm package from fork with yarn + webpack - Can't resolve './dist/

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, yarnpkg

I want to contribute to an open source React Component and I'd like to use a fork of the project in my webpack bundle.

I am using yarn and I tried to install my fork using

```
yarn add github:Startouf/react-coverflow
```

However, when webpack tries to compile my bundle, it raises weird errors

```
ERROR in ./~/react-coverflow/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/react-coverflow' in '/Users/Cyril/dev/MyApp/client/node_modules/react-coverflow'
```

Did I miss something ?

EDIT : when I use the released package from npm, the node module folder contains

```
LICENSE     README.md   dist        main.js     package.json
```

When I use my fork, it seems like the project isn't compiled and contains

```
LICENSE         README.md       package.json        src         webpack.config.js
Makefile        main.js         site            test
```

Seems like I'm missing a step... I though doing yarn add with a github fork would automatically make a release but seems like I'm wrong ?

Comment: I guess the fork is missing something. Try checking and opening issues.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi Even on a fork of the same project without additional commits it doesn't work (and of course the main repo works fine)

Comment: This is caused by a wrongly configured repo on Github. It is missing a `.npmignore` or `package.json#files`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829896/4612476) (and the [full version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829251/4612476) on a related question) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, using a repository directly as source can result in execution error. This is because it's not bundled at all, while the package expects an prebuilt version existing in `dist`. The bundling scripts are often executed before publishing releases to npm.

Some workarounds are:

- execute the prepublish step in the target directory (this depends on
  what the project uses)
- of course, using the published version is the best. create your own package on npm and upload it.

References: [npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055)

Comment: Thanks ! I was just editing to add this info, I will have a look at your link. If it's just for debugging it's okay for me to run scripts locally, but then I'll want to keep my own fork until the PR passes, so I guess I'll have to release my package as you say if I want to be able to use it in production :'(

Comment: Could you just elaborate on the steps required for prepublishing ? I've tried to cd in the node_module directory, run `yarn` and `yarn run prerelease` that was in the package.json. I'm currently stuck at building the project since it uses annotations and I apparently don't have the preprocessor, but I wanted to check I was doing things right

Comment: `prerelease` should do the job. What's your current error?

Comment: I was actually trying to build the prerelease directly inside a node_module folder of one of my webpack apps. Didn't work there (complaining about annotations from Radium) but when I tried to clone the repo in a separate folder, and run yarn it worked perfect.

So I guess I'll just make the changes on the new directory, and publish it when the component looks ready

Comment: Also, just a final note for future readers, I ended up publishing my new packages with npm since yarn's publish was broken for me (cf https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3145)

Comment: A good solution these days is to just add "prepare": "npm run build" to your scripts section. This will get run whenever the package is install from a git URL.  See: - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055#issuecomment-304698029 - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts,
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490565/47185

Answer (score 0):

The package should be updated to include a `prepare` step.

A `prepare` step does exactly what you want in all cases.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57503862/4612476

You can add the `prepare` script in `package.json#scripts` yourself that runs the build. Npm and Yarn will then automatically run the prepare script on install directly from GitHub. You can then treat it like any other package and it will always *just work™*.

Don't forget the `package.json#files` section. See the linked answer for more details.

Comment: Not sure why, but this didn't work for me. I had to add an install step instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what didn't work? Did you add the `files` section?

Comment: Sure, running yarn install when you specify your own fork as the repository version, i.e. '"some-package": "mygitusername/some-package#my-branch-withfix"` doesn't run prepare. Prepare is run before uploading to npm. Install _is_ run though. Caveat I am new at this, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmmmm, it looks like Yarn [decided to drop support for `prepare`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2305#issuecomment-753468942). It looks like they want you to [use `prepack` instead](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts). This should work in Npm too. That might be a more portable middle ground than `prepare`.

Comment: Scratch that. `prepack` does not work with Npm. I'm not sure what it takes to get this to work with current versions of Yarn...

Comment: Wow, I'm not even sure how to consistently get Yarn to run the `prepack` script... Yarn 2/3 have added a bunch of confusion here.