# Automatically Build NPM Module On Install From Github

Tags: javascript, github, npm, build, package

Given that a project's `lib/` dir shouldn't be checked into Git because the files it contains are derived files (from the build process). When installing a package from the project's github (during development for example) the `lib/` dir will not exist, so if the package's `package.json`'s `main` field points to (for example) `lib/index.js`, the package cannot be compiled when imported because these files do not exist within the repository and therefore within the package installed into `node_modules`. This means the package needs to built (just as it would be before release), only this time locally so that the `lib` directory (or whatever other files are generated during the build process) are added to the module's directory.

**Assuming there is a `build` script within the `package.json` file's `scripts` field, can the package be configured to run this automatically in the situation where it is installed from github only? If not, what is the the best approach to ensuring it is built when installed from github?**

There are now `prepublish`, `prepublishOnly` and `prepare` lifecycle hooks, but none provide an answer to this problem because they don't allow any way to differentiate between the source of the install. In short, yes they allow you to build on install, but they don't allow you to build on install from github only. There is not only no reason to force a build when people install from npm, but more importantly, development dependencies will not be installed (for example `babel` which is critical to the build).

I am aware of one strategy to deal with this problem:

- Fork / branch the repo
- build locally
- remove the `lib/` dir from `.gitignore` and check it in.
- install module from your fork/branch
- When you are ready for a PR / rebase add `lib/` dir to `.gitignore` and remove dir from git.

But that is far from ideal. I guess this could be automated with a githook though. So every you push to master the project also builds and pushes to a separate branch.

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055) on NPM's Github with no resolution - just lots of people who want a solution. From this issue it is clear that using `prepare` is not the answer.

My usecase is that I am developing a module that is used in a number of other projects. I want to consume the latest version of the module without having to push out a release to NPM whenever I update the codebase - I would rather push out fewer releases when I am ready, but I still need to consume whatever the latest version of the lib is on Github.

Note: I also reached out to NPM's support regarding this issue and I'll add their response if I receive one.

Comment: I'm exploring the same problem.  In my case, I have a patched fork of react/react-sketchapp.  The only solution seems to be to: "cd node_modules/react-sketchapp && npm install && npm run prepublishOnly".  This could be added to my own package.json as a post install step, but it would run whenever a package is installed, not only when needed (after installing/updating react-sketchapp)

Comment: There is a npm package called "npm-git-install" that proposes a solution but I tried it and it installed the dependency repo in a /var/... temp directory and creates a symlink that seemed not to work.  It then prevented me from uninstalling, so I had to do some manual editing and reversion of package-lock.json to resolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo

Comment: @DaveMeehan Thanks. I think using `prepublishOnly` is potentially really problematic and probably best discounted as a solution.  I tried `npm-git-install` and found it unreliable. Its so strange there is no solution to this. It must be a common problem.

Comment: The original npm issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055

Comment: I'm guessing that package authors don't want to deal with the minor edge case of supporting forked build steps.  It can be dealt with by the developer installing packages from GitHub on a case by case basis, running a script that looks for missing build products and issues the appropriate commands.

Comment: @DaveMeehan this must be such a common use-case: there must be many people developing a lib that want to use it in other projects without a full release. I think this deficiency probably encourages people to push out lots of unnecessary releases just to get access to their own updated lib from other projects. Anyway. I've added the issue to the question.

Comment: Does it work for you to use a local repo rather than the GitHub repo?  i.e. clone your fork of the npm module from Github and then install that as the dependency in your main project.  You wouldn't be able to push your main project and have others work on it without them knowing about the local repo and matching it location, which is the reason why I needed to switch to using the GitHub source for my needs.

Comment: @DaveMeehan That's definitely one way to handle it, but it still involves unignoring the dir containing the derived files, building, checking in built files, updating every change and remembering not remove the derived files before PR.

Comment: you can create [private repo](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) where you push dev branch and then during build process via condition PRODUCTION use right one..

Comment: If this is for local development, is [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) an option?

Comment: The presumption for even wanting to have a different build step for git vs npm seems wrong to me. The whole idea of running a build after installing from git is _specifically_ to generate the same assets that are already built during npm-publish. The reason there's no easy way to do a thing after git-clone is because you shouldn't want to. TL;DR: `prepare` is the right script. It will build the same assets for the package tarball during publish, and when installed as a git dep.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `prepare` doesn't work? The issue you link to doesn't reference `prepare` in a way that suggests it is problematic (beside bugs that have been fixed). This works fine for me in every case I've tried to use it as long as `package.json` is setup correctly. The only difficulty I've found is when we didn't realize that `.gitignore` was messing with our builds.

Answer (score 41):

## `prepare` is the correct way, but *might seem* broken

If you have a repository with source files but a "build" step is necessary to use it,
**`prepare` does exactly what you want in all cases** (as of npm 4).

> `prepare`: Run both BEFORE the package is packed and published, on local `npm install` without any arguments, and when installing git dependencies.

You can even put your build dependencies into `devDependencies` and they will be installed before `prepare` is executed.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/cinderblock/node-MLX90363/tree/09d44d8abc94f728f1c5ea93c22fe9b4f87d9076) of a package of mine that uses this method.

---

#### Problems with `.gitignore` - `prepare` will *seem* broken

There is one issue with this option that gets many people.
When preparing a dependency, Npm and Yarn will keep **only** the files that are listed in the `files` section of `package.json`.

One might see that [`files` defaults to all files being included](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#files) and think they're done.
What is easily missed is that:

- `.npmignore` *mostly* overrides the `files` directive **and**,
- if `.npmignore` does not exist, `.gitignore` is used instead.

So, if you have your built files listed in `.gitignore`, like a sane person, and don't do anything else, **`prepare` will *seem* broken**.

If you fix `files` to only include the built files or add an empty `.npmignore`, you're all set.

*My recommendation is to set `files` (or, by inversion, `.npmignore`) such that the only files **actually published** are those needed by users of the published package. Imho, there is no need to include uncompiled sources in published packages.*

Comment: except it runs the build 2 times - https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/36682d4482cddee0acc55e8d75b3bee6e78fff37/lib/pack.js#L294

Comment: @KamilTomšík I don't think that is an accurate statement. The code you reference looks to only build once. I've also tried testing this directly and see no evidence of the build running twice.

Comment: I know it does npm install (silently) during the `prepareGitDep` phase, but you might be right that the package might then not be built again if you do it only in prepare phase, but unfortunately for my case, it does because I do both typescript compilation and native module compilation which has to be done after install, and hence it's done two times (first in prepareGitDep during npm install and second when the packaged result is installed) - try installing this https://github.com/cztomsik/graffiti (it takes forever)

Comment: @CameronTacklind Hey Thanks for the answer, You approach works when installing a package in project/directly but fails when trying to install at globally. I have a use case where i need to install Typescript package globally.

Comment: @Meet How does it fail? What is the error? Seems like something that may require more attention than can be delivered in a SO comment. Additionally, I've rarely found that packages actually need (or even should) be installed globally. `npx` handles all the cases where I might have wanted globally installed packages in a more predictable way.

Answer (score 36):

## Edit: Detecting if the package is being installed from git repo

I didn't understand the question properly.
Below are things that I wrote but are a bit off-topic.
For now if you want to run build.js **only** when installing from repo:

Files in repo:

```
 .gitignore
 .npmignore
 ThisIsNpmPackage
 build.js
 package.json
```

The `.gitginore`:

```
ThisIsNpmPackage
```

The `.npmignore`:

```
!ThisIsNpmPackage
```

In the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "( [ ! -f ./ThisIsNpmPackage ] && [ ! -f ./AlreadyInstalled ] && echo \"\" > ./AlreadyInstalled && npm install . && node ./build.js ) || echo \"SKIP: NON GIT SOURCE\""
}
```

The idea is to make file `ThisIsNpmPackage` available on the repo, but not in npm package.
Install hook it's just a piece of bashy script to check if `ThisIsNpmPackage` exists. If yes then we execute `npm install .` (this will ensure we have `devDependencies`. File `AlreadyInstalled` is generated to prevent infinite looping
(npm install will recursively invoke install hook)

When publishing I do `git push` and `npm publish`
**Note that npm publish can be automated via CI tools - githooks**

This little hack with file `ThisIsNpmPackage` makes the source detection available.

Results of invoking `npm install dumb-package`:

> "SKIP: NON-GIT SOURCE"

And executing `npm install https://github.com/styczynski/dumb-package`

> Files will be built

## The issues

The main issues we are facing here are the following ones:

- Have to do `npm publish ...` everytime
  Sometimes it's too much pain to fix a small bug, then push to the repo and forget to publish on npm. When I was working with a microservices-based project that has about 5 standalone subprojects divided into modules the problem that I found an issue, fixed it and forget to publish in every place I had to was really annoying.
- Don't want to push `lib` into the repo, because it's derived from sources
- Rebasing and merging is even more annoying.
- No mess with `.gitgnore`

  Heck, I know that problem when you have a troublesome files that you have to include inside repo but never modify them, or sometimes remove? That's just sick.

## Edit: npm hooks

As @Roy Tinker mentioned there exist ability for a package to execute a command when installed.
It can be achieved via npm hooks.

```
"install": "npm run build"
```

And we execute the:

`npm install https://github.com/<user>/<package>`

**Edit:**
OP question from comments:

> But this will run an install for everyone downloading the module from npm right? This is hugely problematic given that dev dependencies will not be installed for anyone downloading the module from npm. The libs used to build the app - babel etc will not be installed.

**Note:** But **if you want a specific version of the package (production/dev)** with or without dev dependencies you can install it via:

`npm install --only=dev`

> The --only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]} argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV.

A better solution, in my opinion, is to use:

```
npm install <git remote url>
```

And then inside package.json specify:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build"
}
```

> If the package being installed contains a prepare script, its dependencies and devDependencies will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.

Example:

```
npm install git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
```

Read the npm docs there:  [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

## Edit: proxy module (advanced technique)

It's kind of bad practice, but good to know.

Sometimes (as in case of *Electron framework* you need to install other external packages or resources/modules depending on various conditions).

In these cases the proxy idea is used:

- You make a module that behaves like installer and installs all depending things you want

In your case **prepare script** will be enough, but I leave this option, because it may be sometimes helpful.

The idea is that you write a module and write a *install kook for it*:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "<do the install>"
}
```

In this scenario you can place there:

```
npm install . && npm run build
```

Which install all devDependencies anyway (as beforementioned prepare case do), but it's a bit of hacking.

If you want do the real *hacking* there:

```
 "scripts": {
    "install": "curl -L -J -O \"<some_url>\""
 }
```

which manually download files using -nix command `curl`

It should be avoided but it's an option in case of the module that has huge binary files for each platform and you don't want to install them all.

Like in case of *Electron* where you have compiled binaries (each for the separate platform)

So you want people to make `install package` not `install package-linux` or `package-window` etc.

So you provide custom `install` script in the `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "install": "node ./install_platform_dep.js"
  }
}
```

Then when installing `module` the `install_platform_dep.js`  script will be executed. Inside `install_platform_dep.js` you place:

```
// For Windows...
if(process.platform === 'win32') {
    // Trigger Windows module installation
    exec('npm install fancy-module-windows', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
         // Some error handling...
    }
} else if ... // Process other OS'es
```

And this **in purely manual way** installs everything.

**Note:** Once again this approach is usable with platform-depending modules and if you use that it's probably design issue with your code.

## Build on CI

What comes to my mind is the solution that I used really for a long time (automatic building with CI services).

Most of the CI services' main purpose is to *test/build/publish* your code when pushing to the branch or doing other actions with the repo.

The idea is that you provide settings file (like *travis.yml* or *.gitlab-ci.yml*) and the tools take care of the rest.

If you *really* don't want to include the lib into the project, just trust CI to do everything:

- Githook will trigger building on commit (on a branch or any other - it's just a matter of configs)
- CI will build your files then pass them to the test phase and publish

Now i'm working on **Gitlab** on my own project doing (as a part of hobby) some webpage. The **Gitlab** configuration that builds the project looks like this:

```
image: tetraweb/php

cache:
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - public_html/
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  
build_product:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run test

build_product:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
  
deploy_product:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm run deploy
```

When I merge into the main branch the following events happen:

- CI runs `build` stage
- If the build succeeds then `test` stage is launched
- If `test` phase is ok then finally the stage `deploy` is triggered

The script is the list of unix commands to be executed.

You can specify any Docker image in the config, so use in fact any Unix version you want with some (or not) preinstalled tools.

There is a package [deploy-to-git](https://github.com/finom/deploy-to-git) which deploys artefacts to the desired repo branch.

Or here (for Travis CI) the piece of config that publishes artefacts to the repo:

[travis-publish-to-git](https://gist.github.com/Maumagnaguagno/84a9807ed71d233e5d3f)

(I used it by myself)

Then, of course, you can let CI run:

```
npm publish .
```

Because CI executes Unix commands then it can (at least a bunch of CI providers there):

- Publish tags (release tag maybe?)
- Trigger script to update version of the project in all READMEs and everywhere
- Send you a notification if all phases succeeded

So what I do:
I commit, push and let the tools do everything else I want.
In the meantime, I make other changes and after one to ten minutes get update report by mail.

There is plenty of CI provider there:

- [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org)
- [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/)
- [Gitlab CI for Gitlab Projects](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/)

Here I attach another example of my other project (*.travis.yml*):

```
language: generic
install:
    - npm install
script:
    - chmod u+x ./utest.sh 
    - chmod u+x ./self_test/autodetection_cli/someprogram.sh
    - cd self_test && bash ../utest.sh --ttools stime --tno-spinner
```

If you set up CI to push and publish your package you can be always sure to use the latest cutting-edge version of your code without worrying about **eh I have to run also this command now...** problem.

I recommend you to choose one of the CI providers out there.
The best ones offer you hundreds of abilities!

When you get used to automatically doing publish, test and build phases you will see how it helps to enjoy the life!
Then to start another project with automatic scripts just copy the configs!

## Summary

In my opinion **npm prepare script** is an option.
You can also maybe want to try others.

Each of the described methods has it's drawbacks and can be used depending on what you want to achieve.

I just want to provide some alternatives hope some of them will fit your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I can see how this solves the problem of dev dependencies being installed, but unless I'm missing something this still involves `build` being run for everyone who downloads the package, whether from npm or github. I'm looking for build to happen _only_ on install from Github, and `prepare` doesn't achieve this. `npm install example` or npm install {githubURL} will both result in `prepare` and therefore `build` being run. I've added this clarification to my question.

Comment: Oh I see now I understand. So maybe this is an option: Add a file (content does not matter) `ThisIsNpmPackage` to your repo? Add `ThisIsNpmPackage` to `.gitignore` and `!ThisIsNpmPackage` to `.npmignore` then `"install": "node ./build.js"` in build script detect if file `ThisIsNpmPackage` is present if it's present then you installed package from npm then in case of non-npm package do `exec('npm install .')` and proceed ...

Comment: I provided example repo with setup (described there^)
Please see the new edit - Edit: Detecting if package is being installed from git repo

Comment: @Undistraction I hope it will help :)

Comment: Although I'm not convinced this is the best possible solution (at least I hope that there is a perfect solution out there), you absolutely deserve the bounty for your efforts. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! :D  I did all my best @Undistraction

Comment: Do you mean continuous integration rather than circular integration?

Comment: The `prepare` is the right way. You just need to watch out for the `.npmignore`/`.gitignore` issue.

Answer (score 6):

> Assuming there is a `build` script within the package.json file's scripts field, can the package be configured to run this automatically in this situation?

Yes. There are 2 things you need to do:

1. Make sure your system uses `npm` or `yarn` to install the package from GitHub. If this package is a dependency of another package, you can use the GitHub URL in place of the version number in `package.json`. Otherwise, the following command will work:

   ```
   npm install https://github.com/YourUser/your-package
   ```

   You can add `/tags/v1.0.0` or whatever to the end of the URL if you're after a specific tag or branch.
2. Add the following to the `scripts` in your module's `package.json`:

   ```
   "install": "npm run build"
   ```

`install` is a hook that the package manager executes after installing the module. (`preinstall` and `postinstall` also -- see documentation).

Documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: @Undistraction, Yes, but at this point you _have_ jacked into the matrix. Other problems can be solved separately -- perhaps just move the required dependencies from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. Or maybe your build script could run its own `npm install` -- which will install dev dependencies.

Comment: `prepare` script is the correct way. This solution will rebuild already built versions.

Comment: `prepare` didnt work for me, `install` did on the other hand. what should be the value of `prepare` if I'm using yarn?

Answer (score 3):

#### EDITED 2

It's a great question. It's too bad there isn't a recognized reliable solution, but the following seems to work.

Create a `.buildme` marker file, and commit to git.

In `package.json`:

```
  "files": ["lib"],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo DO WHAT YOU NEED TO BUILD",
    "prepack": "[ ! -f .buildme ] || npm run build",
    "preinstall": "[ ! -f .buildme ] || npm run build"
  },
```

Here are the things to note.

1. The special `.buildme` marker file should be excluded from the npm package with either the `"files"` key, or via `.npmignore`.
2. The `prepack` hook runs when you publish (`prepublishOnly` might also work, but it's nice that with `prepack`, `npm pack` will produce a correct tarball).
3. When installing from npm, `preinstall` runs, but does nothing because `.buildme` is missing (thanks to the the `[ ! -f .buildme ]` clause).
4. When installing from github, `.buildme` does exist. On npm6, `prepack` hook runs the build (and produces a package without `.buildme`), and `preinstall` does nothing. On yarn 1.12, `preinstall` does the build.
5. If you install an updated version from github, `preinstall` will run again, and will build again.

NOTE: When installing from github, it's up to the person installing to have enough of your package's `devDependencies` already installed for the build to work. (This solution doesn't attempt to auto-install `devDependencies`.)

That's it. It seems to work with varios combinations of npm 6 and yarn 1.12.

Comment: This is a clever solution. Unfortunately it relies on `bash` which is generally not available on Windows systems. There is an official way to do this with the `prepare` script.