# Angular project cannot find module installed from github fork

Tags: angular, github, module, fork

Hello wonderful stackoverflow community! I've recently started adventuring into Angular and I come seeking help.

In a nutshell, I have a project which was using the library [ng-otp-input](https://github.com/code-farmz/ng-otp-input). I made my own fork of it to introduce a new feature and now I want to incorporate it to my project. The fork is: [MauDagos/ng-otp-input](https://github.com/MauDagos/ng-otp-input).

I didn't want to publish my fork to npm, since I'd rather it got merged into the original library (a pull request is open at the moment), but I want to incorporate to it my project in the meanwhile. I searched around and found that the easiest approach is to just install the library from github, like so: `$ npm install --save https://github.com/MauDagos/ng-otp-input`.

The above works and my project's `package.json` file is updated to include `"ng-otp-input": "git+https://github.com/MauDagos/ng-otp-input.git"`. This all looks correct, and I can verify by going into `node-modules/` that my fork was indeed installed. However, when starting the project I get:

```
src/app/app.module.ts:8:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-otp-input' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 import { NgOtpInputModule } from 'ng-otp-input';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've tried running `npm install` and also lots and lots of other solutions I could find in the web for similar issues, but none has worked.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

**Edit:** I've tried adding `"prepare": "npm run build"` to the library's `package.json`, in a separate branch, then doing npm install from that branch like `$ npm install --save github:<github-user>/<github-repo-name>#<branch>`, but no luck. Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392815/10303170).

Comment: please check name of module inside ng_modules after running npm install --save ng-otp-input

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't actually build the module.
For those stuck at the same issue -

- Navigate to the installed packages within the `node_modules` folder and build the package using `yarn build` or whatever command you might have set.
- That's it!