# GitHub Fork and NPM Install Not Building

Tags: angular, github, npm, angular5, package.json

> https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox

Above is a github repo, that I wanted to use inside my Angular 5 App. I noticed some styles and functionality that I desired to change/add. I forked the repo here:

> https://github.com/ekwebster/angular-dual-listbox

The problem is when installing the original repo from NPM, I am getting a compiled and built project. When I install from my forked, I am getting just a file copy from the repo, not the compiled and built version of my new code.

This is how I installed the original repo, which gave me a compiled built version.

> npm i angular-dual-listbox --save

This is how I tried to install my fork, which again was a straight file transfer.

> npm install ekwebster/angular-dual-listbox --save

Looking at [this post and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo), I have determined that its because I am not compiling the actual code into a package. Furthermore, I have not registered that package with NPM.

What I am hoping for is someone to essentially hold my hand through this process as I am new to GitHub, NPM, and Angular 2+. I hope I at least understand my problem, in fact I may not, but even with that assumption I am lost. I have come up short on finding guides for this process as well.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and cannot find a definitive answer. I  posted my own question just now before discovering yours. Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to modify the czeckd code passed on to use git, you modify directly as their own components to use, would not it be more direct. Do not worry about packaging problems, ng will handle well, you just use this component on the line。