# How do I customize react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to use the same functionalities but with different layouts and positioning. For example, instead of having those default next and previous buttons I would like to create my own. How do I do that without changing the code directly on node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can do:

1.) You can fork the github repo of the [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table) library, apply changes in the fork, and install the fork as a dependency in your `package.json` ([npm install and build of forked github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo)). (recommended)

2.) Override the css classnames of react-table buttons in a `css` file, and apply your own styling (not recommended).