# adding typescript code from a github repo into angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am working on a 2D profile extrusion for a web configurator tool but have run into a significant issue that I (as a junior programmer and newby Angular dev) can't figure out how to pull of and am looking for a more knowledgeable person to help...

The Github is this one: https://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components and I am trying to import it into an Angular 8 application. I've been trying to do it for 2 days now and can't make heads or tails of how to get it to work. When I try to run the example thats in the folder after downloading it doesn't even compile... (In particular the geometry_patio_example.html) I am missing the minified(built?) js files to run the library.

I am trying to run it without angular here, but I will need to get it into angular at some point... Any pointers and help are greatly appreciated. I am struggling to get it working... Note that I have not changed any code, All I have done is cloned the repository and tried to run its example. (Of course I have run npm install as well as npm build which is throwing an errorlog as well out of npm...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source repo, it seems that it has been released somewhere as 1.0.0 version.

It doesn't exist on npm but maybe you should try to install it first by running `npm install ecl3d` on your workspace.

Every library you want to use on your project must be installed first by using some package manager, being `npm` the most common. There are other alternatives like `yarn` but as Angular does set npm by default (after creating a new project and you didn't change it), you should read about [how npm works](https://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/).

Cheers!

Comment: I tried running the npm install command with the name of the project but as it is giving me a 404 I am sure you are correct as it does not exist on npm.

Comment: That's what I thought... maybe you can open a issue/feature request on the source repo in order to get some install steps or ask for a release version on npm. Better to do it and avoid extra headaches trying to make it work on your own.

Comment: Yeah... having no install guidelines is really a rough one here... Though I wonder how long that will take to do. I don't think that would be a priority task to make it work because some beginner can't figure out how to make it work...

Comment: There is a way to make it work but requires installing from github itself and calling the build script from that package. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo)

Comment: Hmm I'll have to try this one as well. Going to try both ideas.