# Receive a Git Error When Trying to npm a Forked Repo

Tags: git, github, npm

**Goal:**

Utilize a javascript library using the javascript package manager `npm` to install the [`pdf-viewer-reactjs`](https://github.com/ansu5555/pdf-viewer-reactjs) package using a forked repository of the primary repository.

I have forked the repository, now located [here](https://github.com/Evilsmaher/pdf-viewer-reactjs) -- https://github.com/Evilsmaher/pdf-viewer-reactjs (so you can visually see it).

**Current Efforts:**

---

1. Install via `npm install <ghusername>/<repoName>` : [npm install and build of forked github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo)

   *Command*: `npm install --save Evilsmaher/pdf-viewer-reactjs`

   *Output*:

```
npm ERR! code
npm ERR! git dep preparation 
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-
npm ERR! > pdf-viewer-reactjs@3.0.0-beta.2 
npm ERR! > husky 
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled
npm ERR! C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneIFcXeD\node_modules\husky\lib\commands\install.js:20               npm ERR
throw new Error(".git can't be found
npm ERR!         
npm ERR
npm ERR! Error: .git can't be 
npm ERR!     at Object.install (C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneIFcXeD\node_modules\husky\lib\commands\install.js:20:15
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneIFcXeD\node_modules\husky\lib\bin.js:51:19
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)                                       npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 
npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-
npm ERR! npm ERR! command 
npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c husky 
npm ERR
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-23T22_54_30_663Z-debug.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-23T22_55_15_225Z-debug.log
```

---

2. Install via dependencies inside `package.json`
   Added the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "pdf-viewer-reactjs": "https://github.com/Evilsmaher/pdf-viewer-reactjs.git"
}
```

*Output*: Same as #1

---

3. Cloned the project via `git clone https://github.com/Evilsmaher/pdf-viewer-reactjs.git`
   From the cloned repo on my local machine, I attempted to `npm link` to the directory.
   `npm link ../pdf-viewer-reactjs`
   *Output*: Same as #1

---

**Question**: What is the correct way to install a forked repository of a Javascript library into my current project, so I can customize a current repo and still use the package?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a Git error, that's an npm error. It *refers to* a `.git` directory: apparently it expects to find one, but doesn't. Why *that* is, is a question about this particular javascript code, since the `throw` line appears to be line 20 of `C:\Users\bratl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneIFcXeD\node_modules\husky\lib\commands\install.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit similar to [`husky` issue 851](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/851)

Check if you are in a similar use case:

> I am having this same issue when trying to install husky on a repo where I have multiple projects and the `.git` file is up a directory.
> Are there configuration options for this use case?
> I have two projects with node modules nested inside one git repo for the sanity CMS and the Gatsby FE.

> Could you please place a recursive test to check if the .git folder exists in the parent, then parent's parent, then parent's parent's parent... folder.
>
> In the real world, it happens that the GIT is a mono-repo that contains differents folders with different projects with a `package.json` in each.

Also:

> The case you may be in is if your `package.json` file and `.git` directory are not at the same level.
> For example, `project/.git` and `project/front/package.json`.